# Laravel Homestead folders mapping not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead, synced-folder

I have installed homestead following the steps described in the Laravel [site](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead).
The installation is completed successfully.

I have configured the Homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:/Code/Homestead/Projects/RestaurantManager
      to: /home/vagrant/RestaurantManager

sites:
    - map: laravel.app
      to: /home/vagrant/RestaurantManager/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: 'APP_ENV'
      value: 'local'
    - key: 'APP_DEBUG'
      value: 'true'
```

Edit the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   laravel.app
192.168.10.10 laravel.app
```

I can run vagrant up and ssh into the virtual machine.

The problem is that the folder mapping does not work. The mapping always uses the same path (D:/Code/Homestead), despite me giving a different one. You can see it here:

[image]

So when I try to access the app locally I get "page not available".

Answer (score 9):

The golden rule when you change something in the configuration is to reload the vagrant machine with the provision option, so try running :

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Homestead.yaml` file should have:

```
folders:
    - map: D:/Code/Homestead/Projects # Note 1
      to: /home/vagrant/Code # Note 2

sites:
    - map: laravel.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/RestaurantManager/public
```

1. Should match your OS file structure
2. The file structure of Homestead, which you should not change.

Your `hosts` file also needs to be updated to remove the reference to `127.0.0.1` (which is your localhost):

```
192.168.10.10 laravel.app
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem due to the [vagrant-hostsupdater](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater). Just uninstall the plugin using

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-hostsupdater
```

and then provision the machine again

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to know that Vagrant automatically configures the current directory of the `Vagrantfile` from the host machine as a shared folder to the `/vagrant` directory inside the VM.

To disable this default behaviour, add this line in your `Vagrantfile`:

```rb
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
```

Secondly, you can write the windows file path by escaping the `\` characters like so:

```rb
folders:
    - map: D:\\Code\\Homestead\\Projects\\RestaurantManager
      to: /home/vagrant/RestaurantManager
```

**⚠Important:** After you've done this, run:

```sh
vagrant reload --provision
```

---

Alternatively, you can delete the whole `folders` section in your `Homestead.yaml` and specify the shared folders mapping directly in `Vagrantfile` like so:

```rb
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/RestaurantManager"
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows use the backslash `\` when mapping to a specific folder
Try this:

```
folders:
    - map: D:\Code\Homestead\Projects\RestaurantManager
      to: /home/vagrant/RestaurantManager
```